# Create self-signed certificate with end-date in the past

Tags: openssl, certificates

I would like to create self-signed certificates on the fly with arbitrary start- and end-dates, including end-dates in the *past*. I would prefer to use standard tools, e.g., OpenSSL, but anything that gets the job done would be great.

The Stack Overflow question [How to generate openssl certificate with expiry less than one day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947295/how-to-generate-openssl-certificate-with-expiry-less-than-one-day) asks a similar question, but I want my certificate to be self-signed.

In case you were wondering, the certificates are needed for automated testing.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You have two ways of creating certificates in the past. Either faking the time (1)(2), or defining the time interval when signing the certificate (3).

1) Firstly, about faking the time: to make one program think it is in a different date from the system, have a look at `libfaketime` and `faketime`

To install it in Debian:

```
sudo apt-get install faketime
```

You would then use `faketime` before the `openssl` command.

For examples of use:

```
$faketime 'last friday 5 pm' /bin/date
Fri Apr 14 17:00:00 WEST 2017
$faketime '2008-12-24 08:15:42' /bin/date
Wed Dec 24 08:15:42 WET 2008
```

From `man faketime`:

> The  given  command  will  be  tricked  into believing that the
>   current
>          system time is the one specified in the timestamp. The wall clock  will
>          continue to run from this date and time unless specified otherwise (see
>          advanced  options).  Actually,  faketime  is  a  simple   wrapper   for
>          libfaketime,  which  uses  the  LD_PRELOAD  mechanism  to  load a small
>          library which intercepts system calls to functions such as time(2)  and
>          fstat(2).

So for instance, in your case, you can very well define a date of 2008, and create then a certificate with the validity of 2 years up to 2010.

```
faketime '2008-12-24 08:15:42' openssl ...
```

As a side note, this utility can be used in several Unix versions, including MacOS, as an wrapper to any kind of programs (not exclusive to the command line).

As a clarification, only the binaries loaded with this method (and their children) have their time changed, and the fake time does not affect the current time of the rest of the system.

2) As @Wyzard states, you also have the `datefudge` package which is very similar in use to `faketime`.

As differences, `datefudge` does not influence `fstat` (i.e. does not change file time creation). It also has it´s own library, datefudge.so, that it loads using LD_PRELOAD.

It also has a  `-s` `static time` where the time referenced is always returned despite how many extra seconds have passed.

```
$ datefudge --static "2007-04-01 10:23" sh -c "sleep 3; date -R"
Sun, 01 Apr 2007 10:23:00 +0100
```

3) Besides faking the time, and even more simply, you can also define the starting point and ending point of validity of the certificate when *signing* the certificate in OpenSSL.

The misconception of the question you link to in your question, is that certificate validity is not defined at request time (at the CSR request), but when signing it.

When using `openssl ca` to create the self-signed certificate, add the options `-startdate` and `-enddate`.

The date format in those two options, according to openssl sources at `openssl/crypto/x509/x509_vfy.c`, is ASN1_TIME aka ASN1UTCTime: the format must be either YYMMDDHHMMSSZ or YYYYMMDDHHMMSSZ.

Quoting `openssl/crypto/x509/x509_vfy.c`:

> ```
> int X509_cmp_time(const ASN1_TIME *ctm, time_t *cmp_time)
> {
>     static const size_t utctime_length = sizeof("YYMMDDHHMMSSZ") - 1;
>     static const size_t generalizedtime_length = sizeof("YYYYMMDDHHMMSSZ") - 1;
>     ASN1_TIME *asn1_cmp_time = NULL;
>     int i, day, sec, ret = 0;
>
>     /*
>      * Note that ASN.1 allows much more slack in the time format than RFC5280.
>      * In RFC5280, the representation is fixed:
>      * UTCTime: YYMMDDHHMMSSZ
>      * GeneralizedTime: YYYYMMDDHHMMSSZ
>      *
>      * We do NOT currently enforce the following RFC 5280 requirement:
>      * "CAs conforming to this profile MUST always encode certificate
>      *  validity dates through the year 2049 as UTCTime; certificate validity
>      *  dates in 2050 or later MUST be encoded as GeneralizedTime."
>      */
> ```

And from the CHANGE log (2038 bug?) - This change log is just as an additional footnote, as it only concerns those using directly the API.

> Changes between 1.1.0e and 1.1.1 [xx XXX xxxx]
>
> *) Add the ASN.1 types INT32, UINT32, INT64, UINT64 and variants prefixed
>        with Z.  These are meant to replace LONG and ZLONG and to be size safe.
>        The use of LONG and ZLONG is discouraged and scheduled for deprecation
>        in OpenSSL 1.2.0.

So, creating a certificate from the 1st of January 2008 to the 1st of January of 2010, can be done as:

```
openssl ca -config /path/to/myca.conf -in req.csr -out ourdomain.pem \
-startdate 200801010000Z -enddate 201001010000Z
```

or

```
openssl ca -config /path/to/myca.conf -in req.csr -out ourdomain.pem \
-startdate 0801010000Z -enddate 1001010000Z
```

`-startdate` and `-enddate` do appear in the `openssl` sources and CHANGE log; as @guntbert noted, while they do not appear in the main `man openssl` page, they also appear in `man ca`:

> ```
> -startdate date
>        this allows the start date to be explicitly set. The format of the date is
>        YYMMDDHHMMSSZ (the same as an ASN1 UTCTime structure).
>
>    -enddate date
>        this allows the expiry date to be explicitly set. The format of the date is
>        YYMMDDHHMMSSZ (the same as an ASN1 UTCTime structure).
> ```

Quoting `openssl/CHANGE`:

> Changes between 0.9.3a and 0.9.4  [09 Aug 1999]
>
> *) Fix -startdate and -enddate (which was missing) arguments to 'ca'
>        program.

P.S. As for the chosen answer of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947295/how-to-generate-openssl-certificate-with-expiry-less-than-one-day) you reference from StackExchange: it is generally a *bad idea* to change the system time, especially in production systems; and with the methods in this answer you do not need root privileges when using them.

Comment: +1. I knew someone would come along with something better than what I wrote :)

Comment: There's also a similar program called `datefudge`.

Comment: @Wyzard Thanks, indeed I found it in Debian; interestingly enough, the manual states that while it also changes system calls to functions such as time(2), it does not influence fstat(2).

Comment: Both `faketime` and `datefudge` work beautifully on my Debian jessie system.

Comment: And in Stretch here...also using faketime in MacOS Sierra

Comment: OTOH: +5 for finding out **where** to set those dates!

Comment: Can't get it to work on macOS:
$ faketime '2008-12-24 08:15:42' /bin/date
Tue Jan 28 13:27:50 PST 2020

Comment: @IgorVaschuk Meanwhile over the years, SIP in macOS was extended and "improved", adding a layer of security that gets on the way of doing a lot of tricks.

Comment: For self-signed certs faketime works so much better than the complex alternatives. It's just two openssl commands and you're done. I had never heard of `faketime`, thanks!

Comment: +1 for the faketime, nice trick

Answer (score 10):

I'm almost surprised to find that the obvious thing works: whereas `openssl` takes as an argument the number of days for which the certificate should be valid, just supply a negative number!

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 \
    -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days -365
```

Note that this actually results in something very strange: a certificate whose expiry timestamp *precedes* its start-of-validity timestamp. I don't actually recommend that you use this for your automated testing, since it's weird. You probably want a way to back-date the start-of-validity timestamp as well.

Comment: Well, to be fair, I had no idea you could use negative days.

Comment: Can you not specify start date?

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers In the CSR you cannot; see the last part of my answer.

Comment: More interstingly yet, wont the code barf finding such certificate? btw, I expanded my answer

Comment: The start date is still the current date in the certificate. I made it using https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/588249/157973

Comment: for new versions of openssl this trick doesn't work :/ ... Non-positive number "-365" for -days

Answer (score 5):

Or you could use something like this short python program ... (caveats apply)

It creates a key (test.key) and a certificate (test.crt) with inception time 10 years in the past (-10*365*24*60*60 seconds is -10 years) and expiration time 5 years in the past (-5*365*24*60*60).

Please note that it's a minimal demonstration program, so it does not bother to set any extensions, (e.g. basicConstraints) and uses fixed serial.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from OpenSSL import crypto

key = crypto.PKey()
key.generate_key(crypto.TYPE_RSA, 2048)
cert = crypto.X509()
cert.get_subject().CN = "Test"
cert.set_serial_number(666)
cert.gmtime_adj_notBefore(-10*365*24*60*60)
cert.gmtime_adj_notAfter(-5*365*24*60*60)
cert.set_issuer(cert.get_subject())
cert.set_pubkey(key)
cert.sign(key, 'sha384')

open("test.crt", "wb").write(crypto.dump_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert))
open("test.key", "wb").write(crypto.dump_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, key))
```

Comment: the code seem to be missing essential X.509 standard fields.

Comment: This is very helpful. It gives me easier programmatic control over the certificate creation.

Answer (score 1):

**Step-1.** Install faketime

```
sudo apt-get install faketime
```

**Step-2.** Generate expired certificate a day before currentdate.

```
faketime 'last friday 5 pm' /bin/bash -c 'openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 6 -nodes'
```

**Step-3** Verify the certificate validity date

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in cert.pem
```

[image: Certificate Validity dates - Screenshot]